# Biblatex: footcite of inbook items uses book title instead of chapter name

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm using **biblatex**'s `verbose-trad2` as a basis for defining a citation style. Toying with biblatex is still mainly black magic for me, I've no idea if my code is optimally written, and I've no idea what is supposed to be difficult and what is easy to modify.

So, here's the problem: when I cite a work (book, article, etc.) for the first time using `\footcite`, the whole bibliographic data is printed. I call this the long form. If I cite the same work again later, only the author's last name, the title and the mention *op cit* are printed (plus any postnote of course). I call this the short form. That's nice and it works well for all entries... except for `@inbook`, where in the short form, it's the *book*'s title that gets printed and I would like to have the *chapter*. I at least managed part of it, since the book's title is formatted, in the short form only, like the chapter... my problem is that I don't even really understand what command from what file actually takes care of printing the citation.

Here are links to files:

- [biblatex code](http://www.silentdrift.net/biblatex/codeBiblatex201206.tex)
- [example .tex](http://www.silentdrift.net/biblatex/example201206.tex)
- [example .bbl](http://www.silentdrift.net/biblatex/example201206.bbl)
- and the resulting [pdf](http://www.silentdrift.net/biblatex/example201206.pdf)

The pdf is what you need to see an illustration of my complaint (between the first and the second footnote).

Thanks for your time and any help!

Comment: For `@inbook`, the book's title should be recorded in the `booktitle` field. The `title` field should correspond to the title of the work. In this case I'd use the chapter title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had already tried what Audrey suggested to me, but then it was the first citation that got messed up. However, her comment got me thinking some more and I applied her suggested change to all the bibliographic entries, plus I modified the bibliography driver like so:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \printfield{title}% used to be 'chapter'
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor/byeditor}%
  \newblock
  \usebibmacro{booktitle}% used to be 'title'
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

I now just realized, doing some research on the web, that when I've been using [`@inbook`](http://nwalsh.com/tex/texhelp/bibtx-12.html) I should have been using [`@incollection`](http://nwalsh.com/tex/texhelp/bibtx-13.html) all along...

Nevertheless, this works, so my question is answered. Thanks to all those who gave it a thought!